# Email signup confirmation. Keep track with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

in the site in which I'm working the registration is mandatory to complete an order (is an ecommerce site). In the registration process, users have to fill in a registration form and then submit it. An email will be sent to users to confirm the account. After the confirmation (click on a link sent through email) the account is active. 
I would to keep track of the user which complete the registration and then confirm his account clicking on the confirmation link in the email.
Basically, my questions are :Do users which submit the registration form, confirm their account? then, Do users which confirm their account make a purchase on the website?

I know how to track the submitting of the form (with event tracking or destination goal, it depends), but I don't know how to put a trackable link in the confirmation email. I can't use URL Builder, because the confirmation link is generated automatically and it depends on the account itself (each link is unique for the account). How can I keep track of it?

Answer (score 0):

One solution for you is to include a Google Analytics _trackEvent call on the email activation page. Docs here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

This is the method we use to do something similar on our site.